# Change views programmatically after view appears

Tags: ios, swift

I have to change views programmatically. My code only works before view appears.

**My code:**

```
let tabController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabs") as UITabBarController
self.presentViewController(tabController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

If I use this code inside of `viewDidAppear` it works well.But I need something different.

**My system:**

1)User presses to the button

2)I am doing post request to my server

3)If server returns "true" I want to change views.

How can I do this ?

Ps:I am not asking anything about post request.I just need how to change views programmatically after view appears.

Comment: Show the (delegate) method that gets called when the server returns "true".  That's the place where you'd want to do your "`self.presentViewController`" code.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: I can... but can you show your method that gets called when the server returns "true"?

Comment: Sure:http://prntscr.com/6ntisb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your server request is a background task and the server response is handled in a closure... am I right?

If so, you must keep in mind that changes to the user interface always have to be done in the main thread. So push these updates to the main thread within your server's answer closure:

```
{
     // within answer closure

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         // user interface updates here...

         // example: stop an activityIndicator from spinning...
         self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
     })

}
```

Comment: 'LoginViewController' does not have a member named 'activityIndicator' I am getting this. How can I fix it ?

Comment: sorry, this was just an example of what can be done in the main thread. In this case I stop an activityIndicator from spinning. It must be replaced by your own code to update the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

So in your code snippet, you'd want to do the view change when you get a successful result (which I think in your code is "status == 1"):

```
if status == 1 {
    let tabController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabs") as UITabBarController
    self.presentViewController(tabController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Okan did you try a combination of this answer but being called in the main thread as in zisofts answer?